# PHP - imagettftext doesn't work when .ttf in sub directory

Tags: php, wamp

I have a script that uses `imagettftext` to place text onto an image I am creating.

```
$font_loc="C:\wamp\www\image-test\FreeSansBold.ttf";
imagettftext($im, $fontsize, 0, $space['left']+($scale*$inf[0])+2,
        $fontheight, $col_text, $font_loc, $inf[2]);
```

It works fine if I use the code above.  However if I change the font location (`$font_loc`) to be in a sub directory it doesn't work

```
$font_loc="C:\wamp\www\image-test\font\FreeSansBold.ttf";
```

I've check the permissions of that file and it seems to be the same as every other file.  Also I've never had a problem with not being able to access a file on WAMP before.  I don't get any error messages either, the text just doesn't appear.

If anyone else has had a similar problem and has solved it, any help would be great

Answer (score 0):

From [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php):

> Depending on which version of the GD library PHP is using, when
>   fontfile does not begin with a leading / then .ttf will be appended to
>   the filename and the library will attempt to search for that filename
>   along a library-defined font path.

Try adding this before your code:

```php
putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('./YOUR_SUB_DIRECTORY'));
```